# Editing an appointment programmatically

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to load appointments into the interface and to edit appointments . I can load appointments completely fine, editing does work but not 100% of the time. Sometimes I get the error `The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed`

May I ask is there a better approach for editing appointments to avoid `The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed` error. Error occurs when trying to `Save()`

```
public Outlook.AppointmentItem EditOutlookAppointment(CustomAppointment appointment, int retries = 0)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appointReturned = null;
    try
    {
        Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        MAPIFolder calendarFolder = outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

        for (int i = calendarFolder.Items.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            var appointmentItem = ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)calendarFolder.Items[i]);

            if (appointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID == appointment.UniqueId)
            {
                // set some properties
                appointmentItem.Subject    = appointment.Subject;
                appointmentItem.Body       = appointment.Body;
                appointmentItem.Location   = appointment.Location;            //Set the location
                appointmentItem.Start = appointment.Start;
                appointmentItem.End   = appointment.End; 
                appointmentItem.Save();
                return appointmentItem;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            //Error message implementation here
    }
    return appointReturned;
}
```

Comment: What line do you get that error message on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, errors like that are unavoidable - it means the appointment was modified between the time Outlook opened it and the time you called Save. And since Outlook really likes to cache the appointments (it always caches the appointment being edited in Outlook or the previously edited appointment), that period of time can be quite large. This can happen if the appointment was modified by the Exchange server itself or by an incoming meeting update processing.

Secondly, looping through all items in the Calendar folder can be a huge performance problem. Unfortunately Outlook won't let you search (`Items.Find/FindNext` and `Items.Restrict`) on binary (PT_BINARY) properties such as `GlobalAppointmentID`. You'd need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language) for this: ([RDOtems](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm)`.Find/FindNext/Restrict` in Redemption allow to search on binary properties).

UPDATE. The following should work using Redemption (off the top of my head):

```
publicRedemption.RDOAppointmentItem EditOutlookAppointment(CustomAppointment appointment, int retries = 0)
{
    try
    {
        Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
        session.MAPIOBJECT = outlookApp.Session.MAPIOBJECT; //share the Outlook session
        RDOFolder calendarFolder = session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem appointmentItem  = calendarFolder.Items.Find("GlobalAppointmentID = '"+appointment.UniqueId + "'");

        if (appointmentItem != null)
        {
                // set some properties
                appointmentItem.Subject    = appointment.Subject;
                appointmentItem.Body       = appointment.Body;
                appointmentItem.Location   = appointment.Location;            //Set the location
                appointmentItem.Start = appointment.Start;
                appointmentItem.End   = appointment.End; 
                appointmentItem.Save();
                return appointmentItem;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            //Error message implementation here
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, by anychance do you have any tutorial or help docs or using Redemption in c#.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm). The samples are not in c# but it is quite easy to translate. Also you need to not forget to release any COM objects that you are not using anymore.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for the updated answer. Using your code, with some small changes so that it compiles, it crashes immediately for me on instantiating a new session. I get `Wrong OS or OS version for application`. Any thoughts or should I make a post about it?

Comment: Found an old post by you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1b78e26d-d8a9-4e13-82ae-1d23764611bb/error-on-redemption-object-when-creating-session?forum=outlookdev

Comment: Please see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject. You need to make sure that the bitness of your app matches the bitness of Outlook.

Comment: Hi, might be a silly question. Does that mean upon publishing my software, I'd have to now create 2 versions for my clients, a 32 and a 64?

Comment: Yes, if the MAPI system (which is a set of dlls) is loaded in-proc, the bitness of the exe and the MAPI system must match. Outlook Object Model is Ok since the calls are always marshalled between the processes (which also makes it slow).